# Android Get Device Orientation Using Sensons

Tags: android, android-service, orientation, android-sensors, android-windowmanager

I am developing application where in a service class I use WindowManager to inflate a view. So normally the view layout changes its orientation according to devices orientation, but when I open my camera application, the orientation does not changes. As shown in picture below:-

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

So how to change the views orientation as per devices orientation.

Thanks

Comment: the floating activity is not supported in official Android, so It's depends on your vendor.

Comment: I thought of using SensonEventListner but have doubt that will that make aplication slow and android phone to heat up fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between determining whether your device's natural orientation is in **landscape/portrait**, or whether your app's resources are being rendered in landscape/portrait.  It sounds like you want the former:

```
int getNaturalOrientation() {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display defaultDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = defaultDisplay.getRotation();
    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
        if (display.getDisplayHeight() >= display.getDisplayWidth()) {
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    } else {
        if (display.getDisplayHeight() < display.getDisplayWidth()) {
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    }
}
```

~Inspired by code in Chromium src: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/aca91b5d8a53d77e98021d560305a996864df5e8/content/public/android/javatests/src/org/chromium/content/browser/ScreenOrientationListenerTest.java